# Mockito: verify(mock) issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mocking, mockito

Having real hard time trying to fix this issue could anyone help me please?

I am clearly doing something fundamently wrong i have tried to verify each Mock object but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
 Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
 -> at     com.muuves.reservosity.service.TestProductServiceImpl.search_OneHourSlot_TwoBookingAvailable(TestProductServiceImpl.java:86)

 Example of correct verification:
verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()  /hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.

at com.muuves.reservosity.service.TestProductServiceImpl.setUp(TestProductServiceImpl.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here are my tests

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class TestProductServiceImpl {    
    ProductServiceImpl instance;
    @Mock
    EntityManager em;
    @Mock
    CriteriaBuilder builder;
    @Mock 
    CriteriaQuery<Product_Details> c;
    @Mock
    Root<Product_Details> productRoot;
    @Mock
    TypedQuery<Product_Details> typedQuery;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
        instance = new  ProductServiceImpl();
        instance.setEm(em);
        instance.setCriteriaBuilder(builder);
        instance.setQuery(c);
        instance.setProductRoot(productRoot);
        instance.setTypedQuery(typedQuery);
    }

    @Test
    public void search_OneHourSlot_NoBookingAvailable() {
        List<Product_Details> products = booking(60);
        when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.createQuery(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(c);
        when(c.from(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(productRoot);
        when(em.createQuery(c)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
        when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(products);
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setDate("2013-02-09");
        search.setLocation("Cork");
        search.setPrice("20");
        search.setTime("14:00-15:00");
        search.setType("Football");
        List<Search_Result> result = instance.search(search);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, result.size());
    }
    @Test
    public void search_OneHourSlot_TwoBookingAvailable() {
        List<Product_Details> products = booking(60);
        when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.createQuery(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(c);
        when(c.from(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(productRoot);
        when(em.createQuery(c)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
        when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(products);
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setDate("2013-02-09");
        search.setLocation("Cork");
        search.setPrice("20");
        search.setTime("14:00-17:00");
        search.setType("Football");
        List<Search_Result> result = instance.search(search);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, result.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 15:00", result.get(0).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(0).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
    }

    @Test
    public void search_OneHourSlot_EndTimeAfterClosing() {
        List<Product_Details> products = booking(60);
        when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.createQuery(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(c);
        when(c.from(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(productRoot);
        when(em.createQuery(c)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
        when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(products);
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setDate("2013-02-09");
        search.setLocation("Cork");
        search.setPrice("20");
        search.setTime("14:00-20:00");
        search.setType("Football");
        List<Search_Result> result = instance.search(search);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, result.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 15:00", result.get(0).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(0).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
        verify(em);
    }

    @Test
    public void search__StartTimeBeforeOpening() {
        List<Product_Details> products = booking(60);
        when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.createQuery(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(c);
        when(c.from(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(productRoot);
        when(em.createQuery(c)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
        when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(products);
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setDate("2013-02-09");
        search.setLocation("Cork");
        search.setPrice("20");
        search.setTime("08:00-13:00");
        search.setType("Football");
        List<Search_Result> result = instance.search(search);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, result.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 09:00", result.get(0).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(0).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 10:00", result.get(1).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(1).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 11:00", result.get(2).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(2).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
    }
    @Test
    public void search__StartTimeAndEndTimeBeforeOpening() {
        List<Product_Details> products = booking(60);
        when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.createQuery(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(c);
        when(c.from(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(productRoot);
        when(em.createQuery(c)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
        when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(products);
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setDate("2013-02-09");
        search.setLocation("Cork");
        search.setPrice("20");
        search.setTime("06:00-09:00");
        search.setType("Football");
        List<Search_Result> result = instance.search(search);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, result.size());
    }
    @Test
    public void search__StartTimeAndEndTimeAfterClosing() {
        List<Product_Details> products = booking(60);
        when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.createQuery(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(c);
        when(c.from(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(productRoot);
        when(em.createQuery(c)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
        when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(products);
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setDate("2013-02-09");
        search.setLocation("Cork");
        search.setPrice("20");
        search.setTime("17:00-21:00");
        search.setType("Football");
        List<Search_Result> result = instance.search(search);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, result.size());
    }
    @Test
    public void search__StartTimeAndEndTimeExactlyOpeningClosing() {
        List<Product_Details> products = booking(60);
        when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.createQuery(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(c);
        when(c.from(Product_Details.class)).thenReturn(productRoot);
        when(em.createQuery(c)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
        when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(products);
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setDate("2013-02-09");
        search.setLocation("Cork");
        search.setPrice("20");
        search.setTime("09:00-17:00");
        search.setType("Football");
        List<Search_Result> result = instance.search(search);
        Assert.assertEquals(5, result.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 09:00", result.get(0).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(0).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 10:00", result.get(1).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(1).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 11:00", result.get(2).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(2).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 13:00", result.get(3).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(3).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
        Assert.assertEquals("2013-02-09 15:00", result.get(4).getTime());
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", result.get(4).getProductDetails().getProduct_Name());
    }
    private List<Product_Details> booking(int slot){
        List<Product_Details> products = new ArrayList<Product_Details>();
        Product_Details product = new Product_Details();
        product.setProduct_Name("Google");
        product.setSaturday_Open("09:00-17:00");
        product.setDates_Closed("2013-12-25");
        product.setTime_Per_Slot(slot);
        List<Booking_Details> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking_Details>();
        Booking_Details booking1 = new Booking_Details();
        booking1.setBooked_Date("2013-02-09 12:00");
        bookings.add(booking1);
        Booking_Details booking2 = new Booking_Details();
        booking2.setBooked_Date("2013-02-09 14:00");
        bookings.add(booking2);
        Booking_Details booking3 = new Booking_Details();
        booking3.setBooked_Date("2013-02-09 16:00");
        bookings.add(booking3);
        product.setBookings(bookings);
        products.add(product);
        return products;
    }
}
```

If somebody could help me that would be great.

Comment: I've tried your test with empty implementations of your classes and everything runs fine (i.e. without this kind of exception, obviously the tests fail their assertions). Perhaps you could do the same : comment out all implementation and check if that makes this problem go awway. Then start adding code again andtry to pinpoint what addition causes this exception to occur. Then get back to us if it still isn't clear, or post the answer yourself if you can resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use verify method of Mockito framework in wrong way. It is used to verify that some behaviour happened once. 
In your tests you should specify what behaviour have happened (by behaviour meant method call).

Here is an example of test that checks that checks method for sending mails:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MailSenderTest {

    @Mock
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @InjectMocks
    private MailSenderImpl mailSender;

    @Test
    public void testSendMail() {

        String from = "somemail@gmail.com";
        String to = "Danothermail@gmail.com";
        String title = "Test";
        String text = "Hello world!";

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(title);
        message.setText(text);

        mailSender.sendMail(to, title, text);

        Mockito.verify(javaMailSender).send(message);
    }

}
```

As you can see from this example after verify(..) I specify method call that I want to check. In other words by last row 
of example I check that during execution of the sendMail(...) method of my service method send(..) of the JavaMailSender have been 
called with correct parameters.

Look at the mockito official page. There are a lot of simple and usefull examples with good description. [Here is a link to it.](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests, that you have a missing `verify(em)...;` call in the affected test method `search_OneHourSlot_TwoBookingAvailable()`.

I strongly suggest to reformat your test code separating at least the assertions from test code in each test method.

Comment: I have added verify(em) to each of the method but it doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: @user1408682 calling `verify(em)` is not enough. You have to verify a full method call, like `verify(em).method(a)` See [Mockito API](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html) chapter 4.

Answer (score 0):

Added this to each test and it works, thanks harpun you really helped me here

```
    verify(em).createQuery(c);
    verify(builder).createQuery(Product_Details.class);
    verify(c).from(Product_Details.class);
    verify(em).createQuery(c);
    verify(typedQuery).getResultList();
```